# queue separate continuous animations and run in sequential order than repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, queue, sequence

I think I know just enough about jQuery to get me in trouble. I have three continuous animations that I am happy with. But now need them to run sequentially and repeat. I am unsure about queuing or settimeout. Think I just need to rewrite and combine  but not sure the best approach. 
Simplified my code into a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jessenwells/ntxsS).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var $pulse = $('.a');
   function runIt() {
      $pulse.animate({margin:"0 0 0 150px",opacity:"1"}, 1100)
      .animate({margin: "100px 0 0 150px",opacity:"0"}, 1400, 
      function() {
         $pulse.removeAttr("style");
         runIt();
      });
   }
   runIt();
});

//

$(document).ready(function() {
   var $pulse = $('.b');
   function runIt() {
      $pulse.animate({margin:"100px 0 0 150px",opacity:"1"}, 1100)
      .animate({margin: "200px 0 0 150px",opacity:"0"}, 1400, 
      function(){$pulse.removeAttr("style");
         runIt();
       });
   }
   runIt();
});

//

$(document).ready(function() {
   var $pulse = $('.c');
   function runIt() {
      $pulse.animate({margin:"200px 0 0 150px",opacity:"1"}, 1100)
         .animate({margin: "300px 0 0 150px",opacity:"0"}, 1400,
         function(){$pulse.removeAttr("style");
         runIt();
      });
   }
   runIt();
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jessenwells/ntxsS)

Comment: You could post it here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $pulse1 = $('.a'), $pulse2 = $('.b'), $pulse3 = $('.c');

    function runIt1() {
        $pulse1.animate({margin:"0 0 0 150px",opacity:"1"}, 1100)
        .animate({margin: "100px 0 0 150px",opacity:"0"}, 1400, function(){
            $pulse1.removeAttr("style");
            runIt2();
        });
    }    

    function runIt2() {
        $pulse2.animate({margin:"100px 0 0 150px",opacity:"1"}, 1100)
        .animate({margin: "200px 0 0 150px",opacity:"0"}, 1400, function(){
            $pulse2.removeAttr("style");
            runIt3();
        });
    }
    function runIt3() {
        $pulse3.animate({margin:"200px 0 0 150px",opacity:"1"}, 1100)
        .animate({margin: "300px 0 0 150px",opacity:"0"}, 1400, function(){
            $pulse3.removeAttr("style");
            runIt1();
        });
    }    
    runIt1();
});
```

Working here: http://jsfiddle.net/edgarinvillegas/ntxsS/1/

Cheers, from La Paz, Bolivia

Comment: Great. Thats exactly what I needed. I learn by example. Thanks.